# Warning fstab message

Tags: 13.10

Recently upgraded to 64 bit computer with EUFI
Loaded Ubuntu vers 13.10 (64bit)
sudo gedit /etc/fstab produces the following:-
(Gedit 1999) Warning: Could not load Gedit repository: Typelib for namespace 'Gtk Source'
version '3.0' not found.
Also
(Gedit 1999) IBUS-Warning: The owner of /home/robert/.config/ibus/bus is not the owner.

I have previously added HDD's to my 32bit machine without encountering any problems.
Any clues? Is it EUFI, 64bit, or am I just too old?

Comment: Try `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have an older gtksource version, so you need to update to the correct version. You do this by issueing following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
```

Also, **never edit the fstab file with just** `gedit` Try one of these:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

OR

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```